# my datagridview keeps saying Column named URL is not found

Tags: c#, csv, datagridview

I am getting a column named URL not found error.

I added a new dataGridView and created 2 columns. I named the columns URL and Offensive.
I am importing the data from the CSV file into Column 1 only.

```
 TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\\file.csv");
 parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
 parser.SetDelimiters(",");
 while (!parser.EndOfData)
 {
    //Processing row
    string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
    foreach (string field in fields)
    {
       //TODO: Process field
       DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();                    
       row.Cells["URL"].Value = field;
       row.Cells["Offensive"].Value = "";
       dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
 }
 parser.Close();
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?  Is it 'row.Cells["URL"].Value = field;'?

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint at that line and inspect your row variable?  I suspect it isn't getting the cells, which means *Clone()* might not be working like you expect.

Comment: Well when I refer to them by index (int value). It produces no errors. Just takes a VERY long time to run 60,000 lines

Comment: Referring to them by index should be faster because it doesn't have to do string comparisons to decide which column to use.  I'm guessing that it is updating the grid between each row and that makes it slow.  Try doing this in a **DataSet/DataTable** and then binding that to the grid.  That will likely be faster because it *shouldn't* update for every row you add.